# MYSQL columns into rows with column names

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I want to turn the columns of my query result into rows.  Yes, this is a pivot, and there are lots of articles on pivoting.  Bear with me.  This is about doing the pivot based on a sub-query, rather than a table and aggregation.

I have a query that returns a single row: a person's details from a variety of tables in the database.  This query is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT wp_usermeta.meta_value AS member_id
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id=1234 AND
      wp_usermeta.meta_key="member_id") AS m
LEFT JOIN tabMembers ON tabMembers.ID=m.member_id
```

A truncated version (only 6 columns) of what this returns is:

```
id first last   phone        level cert
-- ----- -----  ------------ ----- ----
25 john  smith  111-222-3333 5     no
```

I want to turn the columns of the result into rows like:

```
Field  Value
-----  -----
id     25
first  john
last   smith
email  js@example.com
phone  111-222-3333
level  5
cert   no
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to construct the query that uses this result to produce the second table.  I get that it is probably a series of SELECT ... UNION statements.

```
SELECT "id" AS "Field", tabMembers.`id` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id UNION
SELECT "first" AS "Field", tabMembers.`first` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id UNION
SELECT "last" AS "Field", tabMembers.`last` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id UNION
SELECT "phone" AS "Field", tabMembers.`phone` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id UNION
SELECT "level" AS "Field", tabMembers.`level` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id UNION
SELECT "cert" AS "Field", tabMembers.`cert` AS "Value" FROM tabMembers WHERE tabMembers.ID=m.member_id
```

What I want to avoid is running the first query which extracts the member_id over and over again in each SELECT ... UNION statements.

Ideally, this would simply be a loop over the column names of the result, which would be extracted from the table schema, but again, I am having trouble wrapping my head around the form of this.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do this. But you might consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Alas, the consuming code already exists, isn't ours, and needs the data in this format

Comment: Would the delimiter `\G` help? (Instead of `;`)